# Checkbox Alignment issue CSS

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with aligning a check box with label, every effort I have tried results in the submit button moving onto the same line :/

Pulling my hair out here if someone can lend any help :D

```css
.woocommerce form .form-row .input-checkbox[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline;
}

.woocommerce form .form-row label {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  /* alignment-baseline: auto; */
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

.woocommerce form .woocommerce-checkout-payment .form-row input.button {
  background-color: #366796;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row place-order">
  <noscript>
   Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the &lt;em&gt;Update Totals&lt;/em&gt; button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.   &lt;br/&gt;&lt;input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Update totals" /&gt;
  </noscript>

  <p class="form-row terms wc-terms-and-conditions">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
    <label for="terms" class="label">I’ve read and accept the <a href="https://propmanjobs.co.uk/terms/" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1">
  </p>


  <input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Continue to payment" data-value="Place order">

  <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="f3a08df9e8"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `vertical-align` property...

```css
.woocommerce form .form-row .input-checkbox[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline;
}

.woocommerce form .form-row label {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  /* alignment-baseline: auto; */
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

.woocommerce form .woocommerce-checkout-payment .form-row input.button {
  background-color: #366796;
}

.input-checkbox {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row place-order">
  <noscript>
   Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the &lt;em&gt;Update Totals&lt;/em&gt; button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.   &lt;br/&gt;&lt;input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Update totals" /&gt;
  </noscript>

  <p class="form-row terms wc-terms-and-conditions">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
    <label for="terms" class="label">I’ve read and accept the <a href="https://propmanjobs.co.uk/terms/" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1">
  </p>


  <input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Continue to payment" data-value="Place order">

  <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="f3a08df9e8"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review"> </div>
```